# PHP Date convert don't works

Tags: php, date

```
".date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $user['data'])."
```

**Server doesn't show me data, he show me only the code. What's wrong ?**

Comment: Can you please elaborate and post more of your code?

Comment: 1. Do you have a webserver? 2. Do you have it turned on? 3. Is your file located in the `DOCUMENT ROOT`? 4. Does you Filename end with `.php` 5. try this: `echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $user['data'])`

Comment: Yeah. my file is on document root. Yes, he ends with .php . I tried and don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand from that piece of code above, you are having problems with concatenation. Please read the [string operators section from php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Try this

```
echo "The date is " . date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $user['data']) . " bla bla bla";
```

Notice how i left `.`'s and the `date()`function call **outside the double quotes**.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. Your question does not seem to be clear enough, so people will downvote it. Please edit your question, elaborate and post more of your code in order to compose a good question, so this topic can help others. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `strtotime()` function to turn the users date, ie: 11-22-2014 into a numeric date that the `date()` function can read.

`echo "The date is" . date( 'd-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($user['data']) ) . "!";`

The date function can't read something like `11-22-2014`, but can read something like `1416685485`.

With strtotime() you can also do something like

`strtotime('now')` gives the exact current month, day, year, hour, minute, and second.

`strtotime('now +1 week')` gives the exact hour, minute, and second of today, but the date is next week.

`strtotime('now +1 year')` Gives the date of now, with next year.

**Note: The `strtotime()` function can read `2014-11-22` but not `11-22-2014`**

Comment: This is actually useful, but i think the OP's problem isn't the `date()` function, it's the way they do the *concatenation*.